# SQL Server : The type of column x conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql-server

I have written a SQL query that does a union and then unpivots it. I am getting an error. I have set Null in the first query for column 15 as there is no data for it. What is the problem ?

The error i am getting is The type of column "15" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list.

```
DECLARE @TemplateID int

SELECT DISTINCT @TemplateID = t.TemplateID 
FROM Submission s
INNER JOIN SubmissionMembers sm ON s.SubmissionID = sm.SubmissionID
INNER JOIN Template t ON sm.ReportID = t.TemplateID
WHERE t.TemplateCode = 'C 07.00'
  AND COB_Date = 'yyyymmdd'

DECLARE @SourceFile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'RCC_CoRep_CRR2_CRSA_CRGB_CVA'

SELECT
    @SourceFile AS SourceFile,
    0 AS SourceRow,
    @TemplateID AS TemplateID,
    'NONE' AS TemplateDimension,
    Entity,
    TemplateCellCol,
    TemplateCellRow,
    [Value]
FROM (
    --C10
    SELECT 
        Entity,
        10 AS TemplateCellCol,
        NULL as [10],
        NULL as [15], 
        sum(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'On-BS' THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [70],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'Off-BS' THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [80],
        NULL as [90],
        NULL as [110],
        NULL as [120], 
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [140],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.02 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [150],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.04 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [160],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.20 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [180],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [200],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.00 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [230],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [240],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 2.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [250],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 12.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [270],
        sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1    AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1   THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as  [300],
        sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50   THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [320]
    FROM  #temp
    WHERE Obligor_Dimension =  'Institutions' --repeat x 8
      AND Solo_Intercompany_Exclude = 0 --repeat for consol = 
    GROUP BY Entity

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Entity,
        30 AS TemplateCellCol,
        --Sum of Row 140 to 180 as R10
        NULL as [10],
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END ) AS [15], --- only to be done when Obligor_Dimension in HighRisk & Equity --ON 2 TEMPLATES ONLY
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'On-BS' THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [70],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'Off-BS' THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0  END) as [80],
        NULL AS [90],
        NULL AS [110],
        NULL AS [120], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) AS [140],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.02 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) AS [150],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.04 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [160],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.20 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [180],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [200],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.00 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [230],
sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [240],
sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 2.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [250],
sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 12.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [270],
sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1   THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [300],
sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50   THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [320]
FROM #TEMP
where Obligor_Dimension =  'Institutions' and--repeat x 8
 Solo_Intercompany_Exclude = 0 --repeat for consol = 0
GROUP BY Entity


    ) x
    UNPIVOT (
        Value FOR TemplateCellRow IN ([10],[15],[70],[80],[90],[110],[120],[140],[150],[160],[180],[200],[230],[240],[250],[270],[300],[320]) 
        )pvt
```

Comment: Does `CAST(null as INTEGER) as [15]` work?

Comment: Nope. Tried that. Same error

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast  [10],[90],[110],[120] as they are null in both #temp and #TEMP

DECLARE @TemplateID int

```
SELECT DISTINCT @TemplateID = t.TemplateID 
FROM Submission s
INNER JOIN SubmissionMembers sm ON s.SubmissionID = sm.SubmissionID
INNER JOIN Template t ON sm.ReportID = t.TemplateID
WHERE t.TemplateCode = 'C 07.00'
  AND COB_Date = 'yyyymmdd'

DECLARE @SourceFile VARCHAR(MAX) = 'RCC_CoRep_CRR2_CRSA_CRGB_CVA'

SELECT
    @SourceFile AS SourceFile,
    0 AS SourceRow,
    @TemplateID AS TemplateID,
    'NONE' AS TemplateDimension,
    Entity,
    TemplateCellCol,
    TemplateCellRow,
    [Value]
FROM (
    --C10
    SELECT 
        Entity,
        10 AS TemplateCellCol,
        cast(null as int) as [10], -- NEED TO CAST both [10]'s
        NULL as [15], 
        sum(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'On-BS' THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [70],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'Off-BS' THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [80],
        cast(null as int) as [90],
        cast(null as int) as [110],
        cast(null as int) as [120], 
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [140],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.02 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [150],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.04 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [160],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.20 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [180],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [200],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.00 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [230],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [240],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 2.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [250],
        sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 12.50 THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [270],
        sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1    AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1   THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as  [300],
        sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50   THEN (ROUND(ORIGINAL_EXP_AMT,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [320]
    FROM  #temp
    WHERE Obligor_Dimension =  'Institutions' --repeat x 8
      AND Solo_Intercompany_Exclude = 0 --repeat for consol = 
    GROUP BY Entity

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        Entity,
        30 AS TemplateCellCol,
        --Sum of Row 140 to 180 as R10
        cast(null as int) as [10], -- NEED TO CAST both [10]'s
        SUM(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END ) AS [15], --- only to be done when Obligor_Dimension in HighRisk & Equity --ON 2 TEMPLATES ONLY
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'On-BS' THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [70],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXPOSURE_TYPE = 'Off-BS' THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0  END) as [80],
        cast(null as int) AS [90],
        cast(null as int) AS [110],
        cast(null as int) AS [120], 
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) AS [140],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.02 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) AS [150],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.04 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [160],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.20 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [180],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 0.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [200],
        SUM(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.00 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [230],
sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [240],
sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 2.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [250],
sum(CASE WHEN EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 12.50 THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [270],
sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1   THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [300],
sum(CASE WHEN DEFAULT_FLAG = 1  AND EXP_STANDARDISED_RW = 1.50   THEN (ROUND(VALADJ,0)) ELSE 0 END) as [320]
FROM #TEMP
where Obligor_Dimension =  'Institutions' and--repeat x 8
 Solo_Intercompany_Exclude = 0 --repeat for consol = 0
GROUP BY Entity


    ) x
    UNPIVOT (
        Value FOR TemplateCellRow IN ([10],[15],[70],[80],[90],[110],[120],[140],[150],[160],[180],[200],[230],[240],[250],[270],[300],[320]) 
        )pvt
```